# How to destroy the APC cache in YII

Tags: php, yii

How can I destroy the APC cache in **Yii**. When I used this code:

```
Yii::app()->cache->destroy();
```

It gave me the following error:

```
CApcCache and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "destroy".
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [flush()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCache#flush-detail), to remove everything from cache. Like:

```
Yii::app()->cache->flush();
```